# Objective-C: Extract filename from path string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I have `NSString` with `/Users/user/Projects/thefile.ext` I want to extract `thefile` with Objective-C methods.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: [path lastPathComponent] or [[path pathComponents] lastObject]. Both gives 'thefile.ext'. There is [path pathExtension] method to get 'ext' but no the same for filename.

Answer (score 611, accepted):

Taken from [the NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), you can use :

```
NSString *theFileName = [[string lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

The `lastPathComponent` call will return `thefile.ext`, and the `stringByDeletingPathExtension` will remove the extension suffix from the end.

Comment: Another solution would be a combination of this and Marc's answers: `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:path] stringByDeletingPathExtension]` (use whatever file manager you want). This ensures the filename is correctly localized, and that the extension has been removed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot! How would you JUST get the extension though?

Comment: @TwoDumpling `NSString *myExtension = [myString pathExtension]`

Comment: Hey, this is quite a bit after this discussion, but I'm just wondering something. How would I reverse this action? I'll eventually add some code to my program to where I can drag and drop a file in. How do I get the PATH ITSELF, so my computer can know which file to access? How do I take the entered file and get the path of the file?

Comment: Million dollar question & answer.. It also clears the %20 in the URL too.. I didn't used the stringByDeletingPathExtention

Answer (score 39):

If you're displaying a user-readable file name, you do **not** want to use `lastPathComponent`. Instead, pass the full path to NSFileManager's `displayNameAtPath:` method. This basically does does the same thing, only it correctly localizes the file name and removes the extension based on the user's preferences.

Comment: For bundles, you may want to use [[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:pref] localizedInfoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"] instead.  displayNameAtPath includes the extension where this code returns the localized name.

Comment: Don't forget to check for CFBundleDisplayName first.

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of being years late and off topic - and notwithstanding @Marc's excellent insight, in Swift it looks like:

```
let basename = NSURL(string: "path/to/file.ext")?.URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent
```