# NSURL path getting CGPathRef instead of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

Currently I am getting  CGPathRef for the path variable below.

In another project I am able to get NSString for the path variable while in this project I am able to get CGPathRef.

`[[[NSURL URLWithString:fileName]path] lastPathComponents];`

How do I specify it to get NSString instead of CGPathRef for the particular variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From The NSString reference, you can use :

```
NSString* theFileName = [[string lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]
```

The lastPathComponent call will return "thefile.ext", and the stringByDeletingPathExtension will remove the .ext from the end.

src: [Objective-C: Extract filename from path string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098957/objective-c-extract-filename-from-path-string)