# Ask an NSBundle for its resource name

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsbundle

I've loaded an `BSBundle` for a localisation something like this:

```
NSURL *const bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                           URLForResource:localizationName 
                            withExtension:@"lproj"];

NSBundle *const bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];
```

… how can I (elsewhere) get back `localizationName` from `bundle` by sending a message to it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36991833/2547229), this works:

```
[[bundle.bundleURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] lastPathComponent]
```